# How to parse a line into different variables in C?

Tags: c, split, c-strings, function-definition

I have a simple file, with integers and characters to be read. I read line by line and stored them in a char array and then split from the whitespace using strtok() and converted to int variables using atoi(), but I can't extract the single character into a char variable.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

For starters this code snippet

```
fgets(line,255,file);

while (fgets(line,255,file))
{
  splitLine(line, 255);
  fgets(line,255,file);
  splitLine(line, 255);
}
```

is unsafe because you do not check the result of each call of `fgets`.

The second parameter of the function `splitLine` is redundant because the first passed argument represents a string

So declare the function like

```
void splitLine( const char line[] );
```

Within the function it is better to use `sscanf` instead of `strtok`.
Moreover for a character symbol to call `atoi` does not make a sense

```
array[count]=atoi(ptr);
```

The function can look the following way

```
void splitLine( const char line[] )
{
    int rowLength;
    int columnLength;
    char character;

    if ( sscanf( line, "%d %d %c", &rowLength, &columnLength, &character ) == 3 )
    {
        printf("%d,",rowLength);
        printf("%d,",columnLength);
        printf("%c\n",character); 
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a different thing for each column, so why use an array?

```
char *ptr=strtok(line, " ");
for (count=0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (ptr == NULL)
        break;
    switch(count) {
    case 0:
        rowlength = atoi(ptr);
        break;
    case 1:
        columnLength = atoi(ptr);
        break;
    case 2:
        character = *ptr;
        break;
    }
    ptr=strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your response, but still this didn't work for me mate. The integer values are read fine but not the char value. Any reason why?